# Volume of a solid formed by a triangle base with square cross sections parallel to a line

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, solid-geometry, cross-sections

Reviewing for a test, I was given this problem.

"The base of a solid is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the line x = -2y + 6 and the coordinate axes. What is the volume of the solid if every cross section perpendicular to the y-axis is a square."

The solution is to integrate (-2y + 6)^2 with respect to y from zero to three. This gives the answer Volume = 36.

However, I decided to solve the equation for y. So I integrated (-x/2 + 3)^2 with respect to x from zero to six. This gave me Volume = 18.

Can you explain why solving for y gave me half the volume of the correct solution?

Extension: Write an integral expression giving the volume when the cross sections are parallel to a line with arbitrary slope. Then solve for the volume when that line is parallel to the hypotenuse, in this case that is -1/2 with respect to x.

Comment: Because you are integrating cross sections *perpendicular to the y-axis*

Comment: Each cross section perpendicular to the $x$ axis is **not**  necessarily a square.

Comment: The problem specifies that the cross sections are squares, so we integrate the area formula, s^2, if it specified that the cross sections were semi circles, then we would integrate pi/4*r^2

Comment: @Deoxal But the questions they are squares perpendicular to the y-axis. If you integrate wrt to x, they might not necessarily be squares

Comment: They are still squares, because I used the formula for squares in both cases, however the area changes because I swapped variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to find the volume of this solid by integrating the cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis, those cross-sections will not (as others have pointed out) be squares, they will be rhombuses.

The diagram shows one such cross-section taken at a fixed $x$ value.

[image: Graph of cross-sections]
The area of the cross-section (in blue) is

\begin{eqnarray} A(x)&=&\left(3-\frac{1}{2}x\right)x++\frac{1}{2}\left(3-\frac{1}{2}x\right)(6-x)\\
&=&9-\frac{1}{4}x^2
\end{eqnarray}

So the volume is

\begin{equation}
\int_0^69-\frac{1}{4}x^2\,dx=36
\end{equation}

So whether one integrates the solid with respect to $y$ or with respect to $x$, one obtains the correct volume of the solid.